# Compile C++11 with clang on Windows (using -std=c++11, getting C++98 warnings)

Tags: c++11, compiler-warnings, llvm-clang

I have instaled MinGW and Clang for windows, and I am trying to compile a c++11 project with the following command:

```
clang -std=c++11 -Weverything *.cpp
```

but I am getting some warnings and errors like these:

```
./fileReader.h:15:90: warning: consecutive right angle brackets are incompatible

      with C++98 (use '> >') [-Wc++98-compat]
  ...19>, 19>, std::array<std::array<double, 19>, 19>> readGravityModelDataFi...

                                                    ^~
                                                    > >
fileReader.cpp:34:58: warning: 'nullptr' is incompatible with C++98
      [-Wc++98-compat]
                    scoe.semiMajorAxis = std::stod(line, nullptr);
```

Why am I getting those warnings? Do I need to do anything else in order to compile with clang in 'c++11 mode'?

Answer (score 3):

It may be due to -Weverything. It is only warning about backwards compatibility with C++98.

Try adding `-Wno-c++98-compat` to the command line, that may inhibit them.